# Is there a function that does a stacked plot on two x-axis and two y-axis variables in r

Tags: r

I am failing to plot multiple axis in ggplot.
Here is the data

```
df <- read.table(text = "Site   Type   Day1   Day2   Day3
              A SD 780 431 295 
              B SD 350 377 255 
              B M 480 179 560  
              A M 240 876 789 
              C FO 840 179 NA  
              C FI 350 NA 255 
              A NF 508 NA 565 
              B NF 405 876 NA  ", header = TRUE)
```

here is the code

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = interaction(Type, Site, lex.order = TRUE), 
                  y = count, group = Type)) +
  geom_bar(colour = "blue") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = Type), y = Day1, label = df$Site, size = 2) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = Site, y = Day2, label = unique(df$Type), size = 8) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 850), expand = FALSE, clip = "off") +
   theme_bw() +
   theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 4, 1), "bars"),
         axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

This is the chart I want to plot. This one was done in excel
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest an approach which is close to what you want. You can reshape your data and then use facets to reach the desired output. Here the code using the data you included `df`:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(Site,Type)) %>%
  mutate(Type = factor(Type,levels = c('SD', 'M', 'NF', 'FO', 'FI'),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Site,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  facet_wrap(.~Type,scales = 'free_x',ncol = 5, strip.position = "bottom")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(strip.placement  = "outside",
        panel.spacing    = unit(0, "points"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text       = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How do I make the first and second column the same size with the other columns? Also how do I arrange them such that they are in this order {SD, M, NF, FO, FI}?

Comment: @MisBlearnsR In order to have order you can add this line of code before the `ggplot` line `mutate(Type = factor(Type,levels = c('SD', 'M', 'NF', 'FO', 'FI'),ordered = T))`. In the case of size please check with `width` inside `geom_bar()`

Comment: It says, Could not find function "mutate".

Comment: @MisBlearnsR I have edited the code for you, please check and see also if you have loaded `dplyr` or `tidyverse` packages!

Comment: Downloading the packages helped solve the problem. Surprisingly it did not work on my other data set.